# Why gdb displays optarg as 0x0 all the time

Tags: c, gdb, getopt, getopt-long

I am learning how *getopt* and *getopt_long* work. One problem is that when I use **gdb** to run the following simple program step by step, the optarg is always 0x0.
Do you know why?Is it the problem of **gdb**?
I tried to search the web and look at the program's assembly code but found no answer yet. 
The debugging code indicates that *optarg* points to agv[3] (value "16") as expected.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
static struct option options[] =
{
  /* name     has_arg flag  val */
  { "num",  1, NULL, 'n' },
  { NULL ,  0, NULL , 0  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int option;
  option = getopt_long( argc, argv, "n:", options, NULL );
  if (option == 'n') {
    printf("%s\n", optarg);
    if (optarg == NULL)
      printf("optarg == NULL\n");
    if (optarg == 0)
      printf("optarg == 0\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

On gdb:

```
    (gdb) run -n 16
    Starting program: /home/ducalpha/clang/misc/a.out -n 16
...
    16          printf("%s\n", optarg);
    (gdb) p optarg
    $1 = 0x0
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out -n 16
16
```

Comment: There already exists a bug report related to this issue: http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13800

Answer (score 0):

(revised answer in response to revised question)

It works for me.  The output is:

```
Reading symbols from /home/wally/a.out...done.
(gdb) run -n 16
Starting program: /home/wally/a.out -n 16
16
[Inferior 1 (process 10999) exited normally]
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I executed the program in gdb with "run -n 16".
I did not include the loop for simplicity.

Comment: Well, the normal run works as expected. However, I wonder why gdb displays optarg value as 0x0 when I stepped through the program.

Comment: @Duke:  if you did not set the program arguments (with `set args -n 16`), there would be none for the program to process.  To step the program you would use either the `start` command, or set a breakpoint and use the same run command.  Which did you do?

Comment: In gdb, I made a break point on main() and ran through the program using "run -n 16"

Comment: @Duke:  it looks like it output `16`.  Did the program exit?  At what point in the execution did you examine `optarg`?

Comment: I examined the `optarg` at line 16 `printf("%s\n", optarg);` (after the _if_ command). The program did not exit at that point. I used gdb's `next` command to reach that line.

Comment: @Duke:  You are correct.  There is something very odd going on with gdb examining `optarg`.  It appears to be a symbol management issue, perhaps related to the runtime library's characteristics.  This is a situation where debugging using `printf()` is superior to using a debugger.